# Null pointer exception in java ArrayList

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am just beginning java programming. I have got a Null Pointer exception problem in the array List
My code is below

```
ArrayList<Arpaymentitem> arpaymentitemsList= jb.getArpaymentitems();
arpaymentitemsList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

            try {
                for(Arpaymentitem arpaymentitem:arpaymentitemsList)
                {

                    if (arpaymentitem.getInvoicekey()!=null) {
                        statement2.setString(1,arpaymentitem.getInvoicekey());
                    }
                    if(arpaymentitem.getInvoicekey() != null)
                        {
                        statement2.setString(2,arpaymentitem.getAmount());
                        }
                        }
                    statement2.addBatch();
                }
             catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am getting null pointer exception error in the FOR statement. I am sure there are some null values in the list. To ignore the null values I have introduced a step

```
ArrayList<Arpaymentitem> arpaymentitemsList= jb.getArpaymentitems();
arpaymentitemsList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); --> remove nulls
```

The NPE I got is
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at payment.Intacct_Payment.main(Intacct_Payment.java:169) and the line is
    for(Arpaymentitem arpaymentitem:arpaymentitemsList)

The problem still persists. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure this : arpaymentitemsList is not null?

Comment: I have introduced this arpaymentitemsList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); to remove null values. Is that not right?

Comment: not if the list itself is not instantiated, then you just throw a NPE on a different location.

Comment: @Karthi That above step does not ensure that there are no nulls.

Comment: Where is the stack trace of the exception. What line does it refer to?

Comment: are you sure that ` jb.getArpaymentitems();` will not return `null` ?

Comment: @Codeman Yes. Because am getting some results.I printed it and checked. After some results, I am getting the NPE.

Comment: If you posted the stack trace, we would know exactly where the exception is thrown, instead of having to guess. Post the stack trace, and tell us what line it refers to.

Comment: You're not telling us the truth. If the exception was thown at the for() statement, the only possible reason would be that arpaymentitemsList is null. And it can't be null, otherwise an NPE would have been thrown the line before. Indent your code, recompile it, rerun it, and post the exact and complete stack tracxe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this follwing steps and give a feedback

```
ArrayList<Arpaymentitem> arpaymentitemsList = new ArrayList<>();
if (jb.getArpaymentitems().size()> 0)
{
        for (Arpaymentitem arpaymentitem : jb.getArpaymentitems()) 
        {
              System.out.println("Description: ...");
              arpaymentitemsList.add(arpaymentitem)
        }
}
//The Rest of the code
```

Comment: I am getting NPE at if (jb.getArpaymentitems().size()> 0)

Comment: That means the problem is in the input jb.getArpaymentitems(). Can you print the values of jb.getArpaymentitems() using for-each condition or check for null?

Comment: Yes. I am printing the data using a foreach loop. After getting some 180 records I am getting null value exception.  How can I skip checking for null values. or I can stop the loop if the null value is reached?

Comment: Use try-catch(NullPointerException) to skip or end the loop. Put this try-catch inside the the loop, not outside. EXAMPLE:
for (Arpaymentitem arpaymentitem : jb.getArpaymentitems()) 
{ 
   try
    { ..... }
   catch(NullpointerException e)
   { return; }
}